# Google Apps Script OAuth2 in onOpen() not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a script within my Sheets document to grab data from Google Search Console. The script uses an [OAuth2 library from GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2), which seems to work perfectly most of the time.

I'm using a function to check whether the user still has API access - called hasAccess() - in order to display menu items appropriately. The trouble is, though the function works everywhere else, it doesn't work in the onOpen function... the place I really need it to!

I was wondering whether this had anything to do with permissions? Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm losing the will to live!

You can see my code here (I've cut out most of the bits that seemed irrelevant):

```
// Setup on sheet open
function onOpen(e) {
  // Set date validation
  range = sheet.getRange('A2:A');
  range.setDataValidation(dateRule);

  // Check auth mode
  if (e && e.authMode === ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE) {
    // Add an enable menu item (works in all authorization modes).
    menu.addItem('Enable add-on', 'onOpen');
  } else {
    // Add setup option
    menu
    .addItem('Setup', 'setupDialog')
    .addToUi();

    // Check if API service has been authorized and allow functions
    var service = getService();

    // THE FOLLOWING RESULT IS ALWAYS FALSE :(
    Logger.log(service.hasAccess());

    if (service.hasAccess()) {
      // Add start option
      menu
      .addItem('Start', 'startDialog')
      .addToUi();

      // Add get dates option
      menu
      .addItem('Get dates', 'getDates')
      .addToUi();
    }
  }

  // Add help option
  menu
  .addItem('Help...', 'helpDialog')
  .addToUi();
}

function test() {
  var service = getService();

  // BUT THIS WORKS..?
  Logger.log(service.hasAccess());
}


/*** OAUTH2 FUNCTIONS ***/

// Much of the following is adapted from Martin Hawksey's OAuth2 solution for Blogger - check it out!
// https://mashe.hawksey.info/2015/10/setting-up-oauth2-access-with-google-apps-script-blogger-api-example/

// Create OAuth2 service using library
function getService() {
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store.
  return OAuth2.createService('searchConsole')

  // Set the endpoint URLs, which are the same for all Google services.
  .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
  .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

  // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
  .setClientId(userProperties.getProperty('clientId'))
  .setClientSecret(userProperties.getProperty('clientSecret'))

  // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
  // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
  .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

  // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

  // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
  // this is blogger read only scope for write access is:
  // https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger
  .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly')

  // Below are Google-specific OAuth2 parameters.

  // Sets the login hint, which will prevent the account chooser screen
  // from being shown to users logged in with multiple accounts.
  .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())

  // Requests offline access.
  .setParam('access_type', 'offline')

  // Forces the approval prompt every time. This is useful for testing,
  // but not desirable in a production application.
  .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
}

// Handle OAuth2 callback
function authCallback(request) {
  var searchConsoleService = getService(),
      isAuthorized = searchConsoleService.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
  }
}
```

Comment: rename your function to something else and set up an installable onOpen trigger (menu/edit/current project triggers in the script editor), the "normal" onOpen has no  way to use functions that need permissions.

Comment: Thanks Serge. Is this because of the restrictions on quick triggers? And is there no other way around the problem, as I'd like to allow people to copy this document?

Answer (score 0):

The way I made for make `onOpen` function to works is as follows:

- Create the `onOpen` function with your custom code (i.e. the functionality).
- In your main function - the one that executes once the spreadsheet is open - , add the followind code:

---

```
// Set trigger programatically - adding the "onOpen" function: 
ScriptApp.newTrigger("onOpen")
.forSpreadsheet(SPREADSHEET_ID)
.onOpen()
.create();
```

---

This is the full code:

```
/** This is the main function that executes once the spreadsheet is open: */
function startProgram() {
    // Set trigger programatically - adding the "onOpen" function: 
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("onOpen")
      .forSpreadsheet(SPREADSHEET_ID)
      .onOpen()
      .create();
}

/** onOpen function that adds items to select in the spreadsheet: */
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('My Menu')
    .addItem('Show message', 'showMessage_') // This is the name of the function to call.
    .addToUi();
}

/** Show alert message. */
function loadCards_() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Today is: " + new Date());
}
```

Then, execute the code and reload/refresh the spreadsheet. You'll see the new menu with the item added to the spreadsheet.